# Sum over cosines = dirac delta - how to get the coefficients?

Tags: fourier-analysis, summation, fourier-series, problem-solving, distribution-theory

Given this formula:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n \cos(n \pi x / d) = \delta(x-x_0)$$

Where $0 \leq x \leq d$. How can one calculate the coeffciients $a_n$?

I googled and searched all kinds of books, but could not find a representation of the Dirac delta to solve this problem.

Comment: The LHS is invariant by the transformation $x\to x+2d$ but not the RHS. How so?

Comment: @Did This is from a physical problem. There's the restriction $0 \leq x \leq d$.

Comment: The invariance, or lack of invariance, by some translations is very much a physical concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a Fourier series then you need a repetition of the $\delta$ distribution at the right.

The ['Dirac comb'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) is defined by :
$$\Delta_T(t):=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-kT)$$
with 
$$\Delta_T(t)=\frac 1T\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{i2\pi nt/T}=\frac 1T+\frac 2T\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{2\pi nt}T\right)$$

Replace $\frac T2$ by $d\ $ and $\ t$ by $x-x_0$ to get an interesting result

Comment: I edited my question, I forget the boundaries, sorry.

Comment: @FooBar: Note too that a $\sin(\pi n x/d)$ term will appear for general choices of $x_0$ (after the $t=x-x_0$ substitution I proposed)...

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: The sine terms can be avoided. I've given the details in my answer below.

Comment: @oen: Hmmm... without the $\sin$ terms (your solution corresponds to mine without $\sin\frac{n\pi x}{d} \sin \frac{n\pi x_0}{d}$) you'll get an even function and clearly the $\delta$ distributions are not symmetric around the origin for general $x_0$ so that you should be in trouble.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: It is a symmetrized version of your solution (there are some critical factors of $2$). I've added some details below.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach.

Consider the boundary value problem 
$$f''+\lambda^2f = 0$$ 
where
$f'(0) = f'(d)=0$. 
The orthonormal solutions 
$$f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{\frac{1}{d}}, & n = 0 \\
\sqrt{\frac{2}{d}} \cos \frac{n\pi x}{d}, & n\ne 0
\end{cases}$$
form a basis for square integrable function on $[0,d]$. 
As such, they satisfy a completeness relation 
$$\sum_n f_n(x)f_n(x_0) = \delta(x-x_0).$$
Therefore, 
$$\frac{1}{d} + \frac{2}{d}\sum_{n=1}^\infty 
\cos \frac{n\pi x}{d} \cos \frac{n\pi x_0}{d} = \delta(x-x_0).$$
This solution is a symmetrized version of @RaymondManzoni's---it is $\Delta_{2d}(x-x_0) + \Delta_{2d}(x+x_0)$.
It has period $2d$ so the Dirac comb's don't interfere with one another on $[0,d]$. 
On the interval of interest it is $\delta(x-x_0)$ and it does not contain terms of the form $\sin\frac{n\pi x}{d}$.

Below we plot the sums for 
$\Delta_{2d}(x-x_0)$
and 
$\Delta_{2d}(x-x_0) + \Delta_{2d}(x+x_0)$. 
We cut off the sums at $n=15$, let $d=1$, and $x_0=1/3$.

[image]
[image]